# Android select device's alarm tone and store

Tags: java, android, ringtone

Hi I want to retrieve the tone list of the device and select it also store uri of the selected on a variable..i able to make list and show all device's tone but uri returns null value...how can i store the uri of the selected tone...plz help me.....
here is my tried one....

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, uri);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 5); 


                 public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)
                 {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5)
                     {
                           uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), uri.toString(), 5000).show();
                          if (uri != null)
                          {
                              this.chosenRingtone = uri.toString();
                              select_ring=uri.toString();
                          }

                      }          
                }
```